# How to run PHP script at a certain time using at command?

Tags: php, linux, shell, terminal

I need to run a PHP script once at a specific time. I'm doing it by:

```
shell_exec('echo /usr/local/bin/php /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.php param1 | /usr/bin/at now + 1 minutes');
```

yyy.php takes param1 from `$_SERVER['argv'][1]` and does its thing based on the value. I've tested yyy.php and the script works as it should. The problem I'm running into is I can't seem to get the `at` command to properly execute the PHP script. I've tried different variants, such as:

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/php /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.php param1 | /usr/bin/at now + 1 minutes');

shell_exec('echo "/usr/local/bin/php /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.php param1" | /usr/bin/at now + 1 minutes');
```

Nothing works. I've double checked and made sure the `at` command is being queued by calling `atq` in terminal -- the job shows up. I think the issue is with how I've setup the `at` command. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: tried to run this from the command line?

Comment: @Dagon Yes I have -- the at command is being queued (I checked with atq) but the PHP script is not executing like it should

Comment: @Dagon If I do `cd /home/xxx && echo "/usr/local/bin/php /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.php param1" | /usr/bin/at now + 1 minutes` then it works from command line. However, I tried `shell_exec('cd /home/xxx && echo "/usr/local/bin/php /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.php param1" | /usr/bin/at now + 1 minutes');` and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much work, this is what finally worked for me:

a) CHMOD yyy.php to 755

b) Use `shell_exec('cd /home/xxx && echo "/usr/local/bin/php /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.php param1" | /usr/bin/at now + 1 minutes');` in PHP script