# can't autometic sms using twilio

Tags: codeigniter, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I can send sms when a user click on a button but i can't send sms when a user set a time or date and sms will send autometic on that times.
in the below code is when a user click on a button for sent sms. Now what thinks should i change to solved my problem.Please help me i need help.

```
<?php 
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Twilio\Rest\Client;
    /*echo '+'.$_REQUEST['mobile'];*/
    if (isset($_REQUEST['mobile'])) {
        $sid = '';
        $token = '';

        /*$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid,$token);*/
        $client = new Client($sid, $token);
        $message = $client->messages->create(
            '+'.$_REQUEST['mobile'], 
            array(
                'from' => '',
                'body' => 'testing'
            )
        );
    }

?>
```

Comment: You want to send SMS in particular time that user set?

Comment: yes you write i want this kind of solution

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: So for that you have try some cronjob.

Comment: i can send sms when a user want to sent  mean click on send button

Comment: Shihas i don't nothing about cronjob or any other way to do it

Comment: [Please refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481629/6663236)

Comment: I think this is the only way you can perform scheduled tasks.

Comment: can you please once confirm you have Added the country code before mobile number with a plus sign like '+1XXXXXXXXXX'?

Comment: this is not issue.issue is how sms sent autometic on given time from database

Comment: Please set cronjob.

Answer (score -1):

You Have to add Country code with Plus sign Like +1 for USA and +91 for India.

```
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Twilio\Rest\Client;

    if (isset($_REQUEST['mobile'])) {
        $sid = '';
        $token = '';

        $client = new Client($sid, $token);
        $message = $client->messages->create(
            '+{Country_Code}'.$_REQUEST['mobile'], 
            array(
                'from' => '',
                'body' => 'testing'
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: this is not issue.issue is how sms sent autometic on given time from database

Comment: Then you have to try cron jobs for that. you have to make a loop of all numbers that will be passed one by one in code.

Comment: i saw it but i can't understant how to implement on this code

Comment: make a URL which can be direct access without any login and set that URL in your cron jobs at Cpanel and set a time on that. when you want to send messages to everyone.